# Why when adding a TextMesh component to each 'go' created GameObject the TextMesh variable is null?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void CreateObject()
    {
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10f, 10f), Random.Range(-5f, 5f), Random.Range(-10f, 10f));
        GameObject go = Instantiate(objectPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
        createdObjects.Add(go);
        rotationSpeeds.Add(Random.Range(minRotationSpeed, maxRotationSpeed));
        rotationTimers.Add(rotationSpeedChangeInterval);
        currentObjectCount++;

        // Add a TextMesh component to display the rotation speed
        TextMesh textMesh = go.GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>();
        if (textMesh == null)
        {
            textMesh = go.AddComponent<TextMesh>();
        }
        textMesh.text = rotationSpeeds[currentObjectCount - 1].ToString();
        textMesh.anchor = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
        textMesh.alignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        textMesh.fontSize = 12;
        textMesh.color = Color.white;
    }
```

after this lines:

```
TextMesh textMesh = go.GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>();
        if (textMesh == null)
        {
            textMesh = go.AddComponent<TextMesh>();
        }
```

textMesh is null.

and if I'm trying it this way:

```
TextMesh textMesh = go.GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>();
        if (textMesh == null)
        {
            textMesh = go.AddComponent<TextMesh>();
        }

        textMesh = go.GetComponent<TextMesh>();

        textMesh.text = rotationSpeeds[currentObjectCount - 1].ToString();
        textMesh.anchor = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
        textMesh.alignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        textMesh.fontSize = 12;
        textMesh.color = Color.white;
```

there is exception error in the editor:

MissingComponentException: There is no 'TextMesh' attached to the "Cube(Clone)" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a TextMesh to the game object "Cube(Clone)". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

what i want to archive is to add a TextMesh component to each 'go' created GameObject.

Comment: Possibly because its not on a canvas?

Comment: Also isnt it TextMeshPro ? Not textmesh?

Comment: The 2nd method will cause nre if the component was found on a child.  You should avoid using legacy components where possible.  Maybe you meant to use TextMeshPro component instead, as suggested by @BugFinder

Comment: @BugFinder `TextMesh` also exists / existed at least ... it was basically replaced by `TextMeshPro` (that's why the name) => `TextMesh` shouldn't be used anymore

Comment: `what i want to archive is to add a TextMesh component to each 'go' created GameObject.` why not rather already add the component as part of the prefab and make your field of according type .. then you don't have to go for chances but already know for sure it is there ...